# single-cookie-header setting for htmlunit

Tags: htmlunit

A web app that I'm trying to login with htmlunit is expecting all cookie key/value on a single Cookie request header.

All searches on this topic ends with a link that supposedly has a workaround. http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/phpwiki/index.php/SingleCookieHeader but the link is now dead.

Anyone know how to solve this problem? Or has a cached copy of the above mentioned link?

Also found a patch here http://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/feature-requests/72/ describing the problem but the patch itself never made it into htmlunit's build.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the cookies you need by calling

```
Set<Cookie> cookies = webClient.getCookieManager().getCookies();
```

and you can construct a custom request and send the cookies as a single request header.